# Why is the Fetch API not working on my machine?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, fetch-api

Pulling my hair out trying to figure out what's going wrong here.

I'm trying to test a simple fetch request in the Chrome devtools console, but every fetch request I make returns `net::ERR_FAILED`. I have tried multiple free APIs but continue to receive the same error over and over.

```
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(resp => console.log(resp));
  
  // VM79:1 GET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts net::ERR_FAILED
```

Or:

```
  fetch('https://picsum.photos/id/0/info').then(resp => console.log(resp))

  // => VM375:1 GET https://picsum.photos/id/0/info net::ERR_FAILED
```

What is going on here? These endpoints work when I visit them in browser. I recently switched to an M1 MacBook pro. Is that the problem? Very confused as to why none of my fetch requests are currently working.

Comment: They both worked for me. This might be an issue with switching to the other device but rest assured those endpoints are functional.

Comment: Both endpoints also work for me - restart Chrome OP or perhaps connectivity was down during the requests?

Comment: The endpoints work when I visit them in browser, but for some reason fetch is not working. Just restarted my machine and tried it again but I'm getting the same errors :(

Comment: What page are you on with the console open? You cannot make XHR requests from the _new tab_ page for example

Comment: Turns out that it was because I was in a new tab. Super weird, because I've been using fetch from an empty tab for quite some time without issue. Looks like [the new Chrome release patches the fetch API](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/09/) which might be why it no longer works.